# Reading huge line of string from text file

Tags: java, string, memory-leaks, io

I have a large text file but doesn't have any line break. It just contains a long String (1 huge line of String with all ASCII characters), but so far anything works just fine as I can be able to read the whole line into memory in Java, but i am wondering if there could be a memory leak issue as the file becomes so big like 5GB+ and the program can't read the whole file into memory at once, so in that case what will be the best way to read such file ? Can we break the huge line into 2 parts or even multiple chunks ?

Here's how I read the file

```
   BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
   String line;
   while((line = buf.readLine()) != null){

   }
```

Comment: What java method are you currently using to read the line? Can you post some code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A single String can be only 2 billion characters long and will use 2 byte per character, so if you could read a 5 GB line it would use 10 GB of memory.

I suggest you read the text in blocks.

```
Reader reader = new FileReader("input.txt");
try {
    char[] chars = new char[8192];
    for(int len; (len = reader.read(chars)) > 0;) {
        // process chars.
    }
} finally {
    reader.close();
}
```

This will use about 16 KB regardless of the size of the file.

Comment: Its a power of 2 which tends to perform better and sizes between 512 and 65536 bytes tend to work well and 8192 is in the middle (geometrically)

Comment: Can you explain more about it please. like why power of 2 tends to perform better and why between 512 and 65536 ?

Comment: Computer memory is usually sized in powers of 2 as computer use binary numbers. A disk block is always a power of 2. A memory page size is a power of 2 e.g. 4096.  Cache sizes are usualy some multiple of a power of two e.g. 32,768 or 3*1024*1024.  This means that cache sizes (typically 64 bytes), page sizes, disk blocks are more likely to line up with a power of two (not always the case but it often doesn't matter that much)  This gives a slight advantage to sue a power of two size.

Comment: The over head of a system call is reduced as you increase the block size, however very large blocks tend to suffer from overflowing caches e.g. the primary cache is often 32 KB.  In benchmarks, transfering around these sizes gives the best performance.

Answer (score 3):

There won't be any kind of *memory-leak*, as the JVM has its own garbage collector. However you will probably run out of heap space.

In cases like this, it is always best to import and process the stream in manageable pieces. Read in 64MB or so and repeat.

You also might find it useful to add the `-Xmx` parameter to your `java` call, in order to increase the maximum heap space available within the JVM.

Comment: i am wondering out of heap space is not considered to be memory-leak ? what consider to be memory leak ? stackoverflow ?

Comment: A memory leak occurs due to programmer error. When pages of memory that are no longer in use by the program are not released for garbage collection. In a long-running process this can mean that the process uses more and more memory over time. That is a memory leak. Loading up so much stuff you run out of heap space is not.

Answer (score 1):

its better to read the file in chunks and then concatenate the chunks or do whatever you want wit it, because if it is a big file you are reading you will get heap space issues

an easy way to do it like below

```
  InputStream is;
  OutputStream os;

  byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
  int read;
  while((read = is.read(buffer)) != -1)
  {
      // do whatever you need with the buffer
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the idea of reading in chunks, you could also look at memory mapping areas of the file using java.nio.MappedByteBuffer. You would still be limited to a maximum buffer size of Integer.MAX_VALUE. This may be better than explicitly reading chunks if you will be making scattered accesses within a chunk.

Answer (score 0):

To read chunks from file or write same to some file this could be used:

```
{
in = new FileReader("input.txt");
out = new FileWriter("output.txt");
char[] buffer = new char[1024];
int l = 0;
while ( (l = in.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, l);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You won't run into any memory leak issues, but possible heap space issues. To avoid heap issues, use a buffer.

It all depends on how you are currently reading the line. It is possible to avoid all heap issues by using a buffer.

```
public void readLongString(String superlongString, int size, BufferedReader in){
  char[] buffer = new char[size];
  for(int i=0;i<superlongString.length;i+=size;){
       in.read(buffer, i, size)
       //do stuff 
     }
}
```