# JAVA: how to read very long lines in a tabstop delimitered txt.file

Tags: java, bufferedreader, readline

I want to read a .txt file which is table in the tabstop format like this:

```
1    ABC    short text
2    DEF    very very long text....
3    GHI    short text
4    JKL    short text
```

The problem is, that not the full line is read,when the text is very long (this means just a few KB not GB or so ;-)).
I use this code to do the reading:

```
try {
     InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
     InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

     while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
           String[] values = line.split("\t", -1); // don't truncate empty fields
           System.out.println(values[0] + " " + values[1] + " " + values[2]);                  
     }
}
```

To explain the problem better:
the result of the above table is this (which should not be):

```
1    ABC    short text
2    DEF    very very lo
```

Comment: You could try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13569964/3998458)

Comment: by very long i mean things like a few KB.I think it breaks on longer lines than 255 characters.

Comment: Are you actually hitting OOM? Or logically, you think it is not actually reading the full line? I'm trying to understand what exactly the problem is when you say "The problem is, that not the full line is read", do you see an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a more sophisticated parser, which reads one character at a time until, placing the characters into a buffer until it encounters a TAB or EOL. At a TAB, process the buffer, increment the column count and then clear the buffer. At an EOL, process the buffer, set the column count to 0 and then clear the buffer.