# How to remove lines that start and end with specific Chars from a very long textfile in Java?

Tags: java, string

I need to fix a text file by removing any part of it that starts with a ":" and ends in "," while leaving the comma. I found this easy to do by just using Substrings, however the textfile is very, very long and when I try do that I get an error "Constant string too long". So I am thinking of editing the file itself in Java, however I don't have much experience in FileReader and Writer. Is there an easier way to fix the fact that the string is too long or is editing the file directly the only solution?

Comment: Read each line, perform wheat ever operation you need on the string, write that back to a new file. Delete the old file and rename the new one in it's place

Comment: can you explain it with some example with expected output

Comment: If you happen to be on *nix and don't insist on Java: `sed -e 's/:.*,/,/' oldfile > newfile`

Comment: Would be easer to use regex even in java. And save the result in new file.

Comment: Could you share a small sample of the text from the file -or- something similar which shows similar text?

Comment: _Since the question doesn't accept an answer_ - I tried some code to solve the issue by reading the file, processing the text and writing to a new file - it works and I was about to post an answer. But, the solution is for tested with smaller files.

Answer (score 0):

You can read very large text file [Reading huge line of string from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569728/reading-huge-line-of-string-from-text-file)
 and after that you can replace ":" and ends in "," by :-

```
myString.replaceAll(":.*?,", ",");
//Example
String x="this :?anystring, is  :?anystring2jk, test";
System.out.println(x.replaceAll(":.*?,", ","));    //this , is  , test
```